# e.preventDefault() not working always reloads

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code and the e.preventDefault() doesn´t work. Always recharges the page. Could it be something on my computer?

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title> </title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script>src="app.js"</script>

    <form id="tweetForm">
      <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username">
      <input type="text" name="tweet" placeholder="tweet">
      <button>Post</button>
    </form>

    
  </body>

</html>
```

Javascript:

```
const tweetForm = document.querySelector("#tweetForm")
tweetForm.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    console.log("SUBMIT!!")
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Move your script (after correcting the link) to before `</body>`

Comment: `<script>src="app.js"</script>` doesn’t do anything. Even if you use the correct `<script src="app.js"></script>`, please see [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](/q/14028959/4642212). Use `type="module"` or `defer`.

Comment: Now the html script is like this, but still get an error: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title> </title>
  </head>

  
  <body>
    
    <form id="tweetForm">
      <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username">
      <input type="text" name="tweet" placeholder="tweet">
      <button>Post</button>
    </form>

    <script type="module">src="app.js"</script>
  </body>

</html>`

Comment: This is the error:                                                                                                    
index.html?username=&tweet=:19 Uncaught ReferenceError: src is not defined
    at index.html?username=&tweet=:19:30

Comment: @SCoder20 No… `src="app.js"` is an _attribute_. That was the point of my comment: _“Even if you use the correct `<script src="app.js"></script>` […]”_. `<script type="module">src="app.js"</script>` is invalid. It’s `<script type="module" src="app.js"></script>`. It’s basic HTML syntax…

Comment: Now it works. Thanks, I´m kind of new to html and js.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const tweetForm = document.querySelector("#tweetForm")

tweetForm.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    console.log("SUBMIT!!")
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title> </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- MOVE YOUR SCRIPT TO BOTTOM, JUST BEFORE CLOSE BODY TAG -->
    <!-- <script src="app.js"></script> -->
    <form id="tweetForm">
      <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username">
      <input type="text" name="tweet" placeholder="tweet">
      <button>Post</button>
    </form>
    <!-- HERE IS GOOD, WITHOUT COMMENT NOTATION -->
    <!-- <script src="app.js"></script> -->
  </body>
</html>
```